# OS X Dictation - more accurate transcription

Tags: macos, voice-dictation

Just for my curiosity and knowledge, from a Software stand point prospective, I read on a book that: "Further, the server-based dictation in OS X also sends other user information, like your address book contacts, to provide more accurate transcription."  What does it mean? How can Dictation improve by sending the address book contacts?

Thank you so much and have a great day.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking this info is sent so it recognizes people and places. I would also imagine that it will use address information to infer what you are talking about and make more accurate guesses.

Apple has a rather long, informative, article on dictation here:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202584

And has a way to change it to Mac-Based dictation so your info is not sent to Apple.